# Use of word "warranted" in the given sentence

Tags: word-usage, sentence-meaning

Investment is **warranted** only when benefits outweigh costs

Dictionary meaning of warranted is to guarantee something or affirm something, so what does this sentence mean then ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another definition for warrant is "to serve as or give adequate ground or reason for," which is similar to "justify." That is the sense of the word used here.